# Why won't the device plugin install in a Cordova 6.0 project?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ios9.2

Why won't the device plugin install on a Cordova 6.0 iOS project? Here is the text from terminal app.

Justins-Air:hipmvi itiMobile$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device 
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device@~1.1.1" via npm 
Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-device@~1.1.1 via registry. 
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect. 
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. 
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/itiMobile/.npm/cordova-plugin-device

Comment: If you are getting EACCES error that is usually related to permissions and not to the plugin. Have you tried running the command using sudo?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @AlexChance.  I tried your suggestion.  Here are my results.  Justins-Air:hipmvi itiMobile$ sudo cordova plugin add codrdova-plugin-device
Fetching plugin "codrdova-plugin-device" via npm
Error: Failed to fetch plugin codrdova-plugin-device via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/codrdova-plugin-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was a permissions issue.  I tried solving it by using sudo before the commands, but got errors.  Then I rebooted the mac and tried again.  The sudo version of the command then allowed me to add the plugin.

However, I could not open xCode at that point.  I got around that by selecting the folder in finder and choosing get info from the file menu.  I scrolled to the bottom, clicked on the lock icon, and granted read write to everyone.  After that, I chose apply to all items in folder from the settings drop down list at the bottom of the get info window.  I was then allowed to open the project in xCode.

Thank you @alexchance for pointing me in the right direction.